# call another applet in an applet

Tags: java, button, applet, call

I want to call (just display another applet)one applet from another applet
. I just placed a button on my first applet and on its actionperformed method
used the getcontextapplet() method. But second applet was not displayed.

How can I display a second applet on any reaction of first...

The code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class home extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    Container c1;
    Label l1,l2,l3,l4;
    TextField t1;
    Button b1,b2;
    ImageIcon icon;
    Panel p1;
    URL order;

    public void init()
    {
        // Tell the applet not to use a layout manager. 
        setLayout(null); 



        l1=new Label("MINDSOFT CONSULTANTS");
        Font fg=new Font("Times new roman",Font.BOLD,50);
        add(l1);
        l1.setFont(fg);
        l1.setBounds(20,20,800,70);

        l2=new Label("Strength of 5000 employees");
        fg=new Font("Times new roman",Font.BOLD,25);
        l2.setFont(fg);
        l2.setBounds(180,120,500,30);
        add(l2);

        l3=new Label("Specialised in IT and computing services");
        l3.setFont(fg);
        l3.setBounds(90,180,500,30);
        add(l3);

        l4=new Label("A total of 10 different departments");
        l4.setFont(fg);
        l4.setBounds(140,240,500,30);
        add(l4);

        b1=new Button("VIEW DETAIL");
        b1.setBounds(150,320,150,40);
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        b2=new Button("ADD DETAIL");
        b2.setBounds(450,320,150,40);
        add(b2);

        try
        {
        order =new URL("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\try\add.html");   
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("HH");
        }


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if(e.getSource()==b1)
        {
        getAppletContext().showDocument(order);
        System.out.println("HI");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you need to post some code to avoid an inevitable downvoting into oblivion...

Comment: Can you show what you have done and what unwanted behavior is? And I don't understand. You have two applets on a page and you want one applet to do an action on the other applet?

Comment: Actually i need to enter some details in first applet. with a button click i want to get another applet where i need to add some other information.

Comment: You said: *I m trying to call another applet button click of other Applet.* I wonder, is it working?

Comment: It's nice that you try that,  come back when you'll have a question and/or some code

Comment: I'm adding your comment *Actually need to enter etc etc* into the question it self. I'm not correcting the grammar though

Comment: ya presently i am getting an error message "illegal escape character" for line 57 (the line in which order has been instantiated)

Comment: I'm going to remove my downvote now, as you've posted some code.

Comment: can anyone get the error in this code??
or suggest some other syntax for the same purpose..

Comment: can somebody suggest another method for calling an applet as the above one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still seeing an "Illegal Escape Character" error on line 57, it's down to the string literal you're passing when instantiating `order`:

```
order =new URL("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\try\add.html");
```

The Java [Escape Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) is the backslash (`\`). Therefore, every time you use a back slash, the compiler thinks you're trying to escape the character that follows it. For example, in the string

```
C:\Documents
```

...the compiler is treating `\D` as a single escaped character rather than as two characters. The compiler error you're seeing is telling you that it doesn't recognise some of the escaped characters (`\D`, `\A`, `\t`) in that string.

The solution is to escape the escape character, e.g. prefix each backslash with a blackslash:

```
order =new URL("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\Desktop\\try\\add.html");
```

This tells the compiler to treat the backslashes as backslashes, rather than as escape characters.

Comment: The error has been removed by the above methid. but still i cant open the other applet using appletviewer. Suggest some other technique if possible..

Answer (score -1):

Try http://www.wutka.com/hackingjava/ch10.htm or simply Google for [inter applet communication](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=inter+applet+communication&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)